# Can output of a method be used to autowire another bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a following class

```
public class Customer {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
       this.firstName = fName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lName) {
       this.lastName = lName;
    }
};
```

I've another class that does the following.

```
public class NameGenerator {
    public String generateName() {
       return "Zee Zee";
    }
};
```

Is it possible to set the name of customer (inject name into customer) without having passing NameGenerator bean. Rather, I'm expecting to inject the output of `generateName()` method?

This question is for sake of understanding if it can or cannot be done and does not necessarily delve into best practices.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the result of a static method invocation and inject it in another bean, you could go for the [`MethodInvokingFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html) class.

The `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` returns a value which is the result of a static or instance method invocation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think if that would be possible. Why in the first place you want to do that?